# Mario NEAT implementation problems

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

So I am attempting to recreate Mar/IO from Sethbling in Python. I am using OpenAI retro to do this. i have edited the game so far, so that each sprite is categorized as such.

```
{
    'block':3,
    'luigi':1
    'mario':2,
    'background':0,
    'enemies':4
}
```

I then scale this down and pass it in through the algorithm, and train based on that. I am using  NEAT(neural evolution of augmented topologies) specifically neat-python.

The problem is, when i start the model, the agent takes no action. The starting image is only fed in (due to no movement) and the program times out. This has remained constant in 2-3 generations of a population with 300. There is nothing wrong with the algorithm itself, as I know this for sure. I then added random noise to each frame, which resulted in random, but at least some actions from the agent. **What can I do to make the agent train based off of the original frame data**, and image that is (13 x 13) in shape, without adding random noise on top of the frame in order to invoke action? **What is happening to the model, and why is it behaving this way?** Is the input data too static and non-changing? I can link my NEAT hyper-parameters if neccessary...

### Starting Image

[image: Starting Image]

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3]]
```

### Example Image

[image: Example Image]

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 3 3 3 3]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 4 0 0 0]
 [3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3]]
```

### Input frame with noise added

```
[[0.00227003 0.         0.         0.57885817 0.         0.57658814
  0.00227003 0.         0.         0.         0.00227003 0.57658814
  0.        ]
 [0.         0.00277295 0.70710134 0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.70710134 0.00277295 0.         0.         0.
  0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.         0.99999231 0.
  0.00392154]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.         0.4472136  0.
  0.         0.         0.89442719 0.         0.         0.
  0.        ]
 [0.99999231 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.00392154 0.         0.
  0.        ]
 [0.         0.00226704 0.00226704 0.00453409 0.57809606 0.57809606
  0.         0.         0.         0.         0.57582902 0.
  0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.70710678
  0.70710678]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.         0.         0.         1.         0.
  0.        ]
 [0.57735027 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
  0.57735027 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.57735027
  0.        ]
 [0.57734287 0.00226409 0.         0.         0.         0.00226409
  0.00226409 0.57734287 0.00226409 0.00226409 0.         0.57734287
  0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.70710678 0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.70710678 0.         0.         0.         0.
  0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.00393682 0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.         0.9999535  0.00393682 0.00787365 0.
  0.        ]
```